# put values back to corresponding users in array

Tags: javascript

From the following sample of code am trying to get the location from text while looping through each of the users of the text_array. After extracting the location from the text I am trying to put the values back to the array where the it corresponds to the right user but it gives me the error  "text_array[i] is undefined". What am I doing wrong with this one ?

```
function replace_undefined(text_array) {
    var userLocationText = {};
    for (i = 0, l = text_array.length; i < l; i++) {
        console.log(text_array[i].user);
        userLocationText[text_array[i].user] = text_array[i].location;
        var text = text_array[i].text;
        Placemaker.getPlaces(text, function (o) {
            console.log(o);
            if ($.isArray(o.match)) {
                if (o.match[0].place.name == "Europe" || o.match[0].place.name == "United States") {
                    var location = o.match[1].place.name;
                    userLocationText[text_array[i].user] = location;
                }
                if ($.isArray(o.match)) {
                    if (o.match[0].place.name !== "Europe") {
                        var location = o.match[0].place.name;
                        userLocationText[text_array[i].user] = location;
                    }
                }
            } else if (!$.isArray(o.match)) {
                var location = o.match.place.name;
                userLocationText[text_array[i].user] = location;
            }

            console.log(text_array);
        });
    }
}

}

text_array = [{
    user: a,
    user_id: b,
    date: c,
    profile_img: d,
    text: e,
    contentString: f,
    url: g,
    location: undefined
}, {
    user: a,
    user_id: b,
    date: c,
    profile_img: d,
    text: e,
    contentString: f,
    url: g,
    location: undefined
}, {
    user: a,
    user_id: b,
    date: c,
    profile_img: d,
    text: e,
    contentString: f,
    url: g,
    location: undefined
}];
```

Comment: as i understood `Placemaker.getPlaces` is asynchronous operation, is not it? If yes, you get a wrong value of `i` variable. You should create a closure for `i` var with specific value on each iteration

Comment: what you mean? you can edit the code if u want

Comment: try to change `Placemarker.getPlacess(...)` to this one `Placemaker.getPlaces(text, (function(i) {
    return function (o) {
        console.log(i);
        // your code here
    };
}}(i)));`

Comment: I have put };});}console.log(text_array);} after the last else if.am not getting any errors but  but am not getting the array as well

Answer (score 0):

as said `Placemaker.getPlaces` is surely async, so here is a dirty closure:

```
Placemaker.getPlaces(text, (function () {
  var z = i;
  return function (o) {
    var i = z;
    ...
    console.log(text_array);
    };
})());
```

it's cleaner if you use another var than "i", extract the function in it's own callback, etc.

basically, instead of sending a function to execute as 2nd argument of Placemaker.getPlaces, this will wrap it in another function which is immediatly executed. The immediatly executing wrapping function saves the current value of "i", and returns the initial anonymous function. The initial function will be used by Placemaker.getPlaces when it's ready, as before.

But now, due to closures, my "z" var holds the value of "i" which existed during the for loop, and can be used long after the loop has ended.

I know, it ain't that clear.

edit: well, maybe [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bChnx/) will help.

Comment: so supposedly i represents the value of text?